# Trying to hover mouse over tabs and perform automated click on a particular item in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to perform a mouse hover over a Men category tab and select "Shirts" category on this [website](https://www.barneys.com/). However I am not able to click the "shirts" category in Men item also I m not getting any error too. Here is my code:

```
public void PurchaseItemTest() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        //util.clickbyXpath(Constants.MENCATEGORYTAB);

         WebElement element = util.getdriver().findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='accord-header' ]"));

            Actions action = new Actions(util.getdriver());

            action.moveToElement(element).moveToElement(util.getdriver().findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='accord-header' and contains(.,'Men')]"))).moveToElement(util.getdriver().findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Shirts']"))).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_ for a proper analysis.

Comment: @DebanjanB how to paste the relevant HTML code here, Actually when I copy paste the HTML code, A huge amount of HTML code is pasted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
final By DROPDOWN = By.cssSelector("li[class='atg_store_dropDownParent']");
final By DROPDOWN_LINK = By.cssSelector("a[class='accord-header ']");

List<WebElement> dropdowns = new WebDriverWait(util.getDriver(), 5)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(DROPDOWN));

WebElement men = dropdowns.stream()
    .flatMap(dropdown -> dropdown.findElements(DROPDOWN_LINK).stream())
    .filter(link -> link.getText().equals("MEN"))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);

if(men != null) {
    new WebDriverWait(util.getDriver(), 5)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(men));
    Actions action = new Actions(util.getDriver());
    action.moveToElement(men).build().perform();
    new WebDriverWait(util.getDriver(), 5)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(SHIRTS))
        .click();
}
```

Your xpath for the Men category tab was acting wonky for me. When you hover, make sure to wait for the "Shirts" link to be clickable before clicking. Also, avoid using `Thread#sleep()` with Selenium. Use [Explicit Waits](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) instead.

Comment: It is working absolutely fine, Thanks for your effort.. But I am not able to understand how this is working(Specially theDropdowns). Can you please give me some explanation as what is happening in this code?